Could not install because the package appears to be invalid
The file I created from Build APK in debug mode is uploaded to my phone, but the APK file I created in release mode is not uploaded, giving the error "could not be installed because the package appears invalid".
My experiments:
I deleted the app after clearing data,
I tried to install an app on a new phone for the first time.
But I keep getting the same error.

what is your package name

my package name: com.gemliksiteyonetim.temizliktakip

don't use space and - symbol

I recommend installing apps via adb install then you will get a detailed error message.

Currently, debug apk and signed release apk are loading normally, only unsigned release apk is not loading, very interesting.
